# C++ array not outputting full values

Tags: c++, arrays

So i'm experimenting with arrays when I come across a bit of a problem

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char items[] = {'bread', 'water', 'crisps', 'sweets', 'vegetables'};
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(items); i++) {
        cout << items[i] << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

What's happening is that when the code is ran, it's only outputting the last letter of each item, so 'd' 'r' 's' 's' 's'. I know i'm clearly doing something wrong here but I can't figure out what. I've been surfing on stackoverflow/google for a question like this but clearly what I have done is so obviously wrong, no one has asked!

Any help or a nudge in the right direction to particular documentation would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: [Use your compiler warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5be7eae80bb7b9af) (and errors).

Comment: Also, http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `'` and `"`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Need an array of character pointers.
2. Need to use double quotes
3. Read a book on C++

i.e. code should be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
char *items[] = {"bread", "water", "crisps", "sweets", "vegetables"};
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(items) / sizeof(*items)); i++) {
        cout << items[i] << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `const char* items[]` would be better.

Comment: `sizeof(items)` is a bug.

Comment: You see, I've been looking at numerous things and some people were using double quotes and single quotes, so i just went with single (impatient i guess). I've just started learning C++ so i'm still trying to grasp the basics, thanks for the help all and sorry for it being such a naff and easy question!

Comment: Also i'm just wondering why (sizeof(items) / sizeof(*items)) works? i understand the pointers part now but i'm still a bit stuck on sizeof, if someone could phrase it in simpleton terms, that'd be great! thanks

Comment: @AndrewMatthew: `sizeof(items)` is the size of the _entire array_ or the size of five pointers to `char`. `sizeof(*items)` is the size of the _first element_ of the array. So you have total size divided by the size of a single element to get the number of elements in the array.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thank you! It all makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

Any of these items in the initializer list

```
{'bread', 'water', 'crisps', 'sweets', 'vegetables'};
```

is a multicharacter literal. According to the C++ Standard

> A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary character literal containing
>   a single c-char not representable in the execution character set, is
>   conditionally-supported, has type int, and has an
>   implementation-defined value.

You need to use string literals. I think that what you want is the following

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   const char *items[] = { "bread", "water", "crisps", "sweets", "vegetables" };

   for ( const char *s : items ) std::cout << s << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```